# Calling New StackTrace blocks when closing application

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling, stack-trace

I just did some analysis by using a global function which is called `GetCallingMethod` in my case.

Mostly it works great. But some cases the **application is blocked**. It is blocked when **closing** the application. When going to "pause" in Visual Studio, it stays on the `new StackTrace` line forever.

In my application I am using third party references, multithreading and several classes. But all that should not be a problem and should not lock the tracer class as far as I imagine.
I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in this case.

Any idea where to look for any solution?

[image: Stack block]
This line will never be left in development area. Application will is frozen. Try/Catch will not force the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use and has never given me problems (debug or production).

```
Dim strMethodName As String = ""
Dim stkTrace As New StackTrace(True)
strMethodName = stkTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name
```

Note:  you can put any integer in the GetFrame() as long as it's less than stkTrace.FrameCount that is.  0 is the current frame, 1 is previous, 2 is before that, etc...

Comment: Hi Brett. Thanks for your answer. I also had no problems on smaller projects. On this project there is a huge multithreading stuff running and I think thats a problem. To use `True` or `False` argument it did not help. Perhaps another person has same problems like me. When I stay on breakpoint the "new StackTrace" is always working on debugging. Just while running the app it is throwing the error.